# Refresh div triggering document.ready of inner HTML multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load, refresh

Here's the situation:
I have an index.php with some links. Each link gets another page (e.g. nicetry.html) to load in a div. This page getting loaded (e.g. nicetry.html) needs to fire some ajax in the document.ready and bind a click event to a button. (actually, it doesn't really matter when I bind the onclick function).
This button should refresh the content of said div thus triggering the document.ready of nicetry.html.

In code...

index.php:

```
<script>
    $("#nicetry").click(function(){
         $('#content').load('nicetry.html');
    });
</script>
<body>
<div id="nav">
 <ul>
  <li id="home"> <a href="#"> Home </a></li>
  <li id="nicetry"> <a href="#"> nicetry </a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

nicetry.html

```
$(document).ready({

//some stuff

 $("#next").on("click", function() {
   $("#content").load("nicetry.html");
 });
});
```

This works for the first time I hit the "next" button, then it stops reloading the div. Since the id of the button doesn't change I was guessing it's a matter of caching. I tried appending no-caching metatags, appending ?val=randomInts to the url... nothing worked. Either because I was doing it wrong, or because it doesn't actually work.

I eventually implemented a workaround having index.php loading nicetry.html at document.ready and simply doing location.reload(true) from nicetry.html. Still, I'd like to know if there's a better solution or why this is not working the way I would think it should.

Comment: To see if I understand this, you click on #nicetry and that loads nicetry.html into the content div. Now within the content div there is   #next, and when you click on it you want to load nicetry.html again, into the div that it's already in?

Comment: @mToce yes, that's what I need to do :)

Comment: I guess I'm confused with loading the nicetry.html again, if it already there? Wouldn't a "next" button move on to something different. Can you post a URL to a live example?

Comment: @mToce unfortunately the site is not live yet. I'll try to explain the use case: nicetry.html displays puzzles in javascript, the puzzles are loaded at document.ready (it can't be otherwise) with an ajax call. Once the user solves one puzzle he wants to solve more, of course. So he hits the "next" button that should refresh the page thus triggering the document.ready again and thus providing another puzzle.

Comment: Ok, it's live now :) http://gointogo.altervista.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it took me so long to figure it out. As I suspected, I was too tangled in my own madness and inexperience.

Here's the solution:
1. make sure you have a fairly recent version of jQuery
2. bind the loading in the index like this:

```
        $(document).on("click", "#next",
            function() {
                    $("#content").load("nicetry.html");
            });
```

Easy :)